# org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor While using Full Text Search

Tags: hibernate-search, fuzzy-search

I am using hibernate-search-4.5.2.Final to implement a full text search but getting an exception with following message

> org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor

in the following line

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(sessionImpl.getFactory().openSession());
```

This is my code:

```
    @Autowired  
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public List getFuzzySearchedResult(String query_string) {
    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
        final QueryBuilder mythQB = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(FaqMaster.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = mythQB.phrase().withSlop(3).onField("question_name").andField("qustion_answer").sentence("Department").createQuery();

        org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery);
        List result = fullTextQuery.list();
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println("ERROR: "); e.printStackTrace(); return null;}
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace? Also, which version of Hibernate ORM are you using? Hibernate ORM 4.3.6.Final is the officially supported version for the Search version you are using. Where is sessionImpl coming from in your example?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a version of Hibernate ORM which is not compatible with this version of Hibernate Search.

All versions of Hibernate Search 4.5.x require a version of Hibernate ORM in the series 4.3.x.

This is documented:

- On the [Downloads page](http://hibernate.org/search/downloads/)
- In the [Requirements section of the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e73)
- In the README of the project
- In the Maven pom files

But you're not the first person getting confused by this ;-) So I'm wondering now if we should add an explicit check and more understandable error message. I've created [HSEARCH-1816](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1816) to see if we can do better.